# Using enums for modifying print statements in C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, if-statement, enums

I have a problem with the `operand` bit of the code. The function below gives the user 5 tries to guess a random number generated between 0 and 20, the user has 5 attempts to get the code right. in the second `else` statement I want to modify the `more,less` keywords using `enums` depending on if the users input is greater or lower than the generated number.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ()
{
     int tries = 5;
     int random = rand() %20;
     int input;
     static const char *const comp[] = {[less] = "less",[more] = "more"};
     enum Comparison {more, less};
     enum Comparison operand;

     for(int i=0; i>=tries; --tries){
         printf("You have %d tries left", tries);
         printf("Enter a guess: ");
         scanf("%d", &input);
         if(input > random){
            operand = more;
         }
         else{
            operand = less;
         }
         if (input == random){
            printf("Congratulations. You guessed it!");
            break;
         }
         else{
            printf("Sorry %d is wrong. My number is %d than that", input, comp[operand]);
            continue;
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please do not modify your code after answers or comments were given. That invalidates all efforts.

Comment: You should put declaration of your enum type before the line where you use it.

Comment: `comp[operand]` is a string but you print it using `%d`. That causes undefined behaviour and should make your compiler scream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no array called `Comparison` in your code.

You can replace `operand = Comparison[0];` with `operand = less;`, and replace `operand = Comparison[1];` with `operand = more;`.

The `printf` for incorrect guesses looks a bit strange. It will print "My operand is 0 than that" when `operand` equals `less`, or "My operand is 1 than that" when operand equals `more`. I guess you really want the `printf` to print the words "less" or "more" rather than the numbers 0 or 1. You can do that by using an array to map the enum values to strings:

```
    static const char *const comp[] = {
        [less] = "less",
        [more] = "more"
    };

    printf("Sorry %d is wrong. My number is %s than that.\n",
           input, comp[operand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Comparison[0]` with `more` and `Comparison[1]` with `less`.

Enums do not work like arrays in C :)

**EDIT:**

This loop looks wrong too:

`for(int i=0; i>=tries; --tries)`<— `tries` is 5, so the loop will never run, since i=0 and 0 is never >= 5. Rethink the logic here :)

Comment: @M.M I dont have access to a compiler now, but that surprises me! Learnt something new today :)

Comment: Thank you I also have the problem where in the print function `printf("Sorry %d is wrong. My number is %s than that\n", input, operand);` it prints out 0 or 1 for the operand I want it to print out `more` or `less` what can I do to resolve that issue?

Comment: @MOehm my bad, misread the language tag. `(enum Comparison)0` then

Comment: @tony consider replacing `, operand` with `, operand ? “more” : “less”` in the printf-statement

Comment: @M.M: Okay, that never happened. `:)` (I was just as surprised as Morten, that's all.)

Comment: @MortenJensen I get `Sorry 10 is wrong. My number is 1818588019 than that` when i implement that.